# Query regarding parallel axis theorem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, reference-frames, moment-of-inertia

Suppose there are two points at (4,0) and (-4,0) each of mass 1 kg and the origin is (0,0). The rotational inertia of the combined system is 32kg.m^2. But if we shift the axis of rotation to left by 2 units to (-2,0). The new moment of inertia is 40 kg.m^2. Which is $$M_{sys}d^2$$ more than the original value. But the moment of inertia of one particles decreased and other ones increased. then why the moment of inertia of entire system increased by $$M_{sys}d^2$$.

Comment: Hint: $(a+b)^2 > a^2 + b^2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a general sketch of the situation and let's try to figure this out algebraically.

[image: fig1]

The separation $\ell = a + b$ is fixed, and the pivot is some distance $d$ from the combined center of mass in the middle. The distance from the pivot to each mass is assigned the letters $a$ and $b$.

Each mass is $m$ such that $M_{\rm sys} = 2m$

I will find the MMOI about the pivot, two different ways.

1. Account for the MMOI about the center and use the parallel axis theorem to move to the pivot

   - MMOI at the center of mass $I_{\rm COM} = m \left( \tfrac{\ell}{2} \right)^2 + m \left( \tfrac{\ell}{2} \right)^2 = \tfrac{m}{2} \ell^2 = \tfrac{1}{2} M_{\rm sys} \left( \tfrac{1}{2} \ell^2 \right) $
   - MMOI at the pivot $I_{\rm PVT} = I_{\rm COM} + M_{\rm sys} d^2 = \tfrac{1}{2} M_{\rm sys}  \left( \tfrac{1}{2} \ell^2 + 2\,d^2\right) \tag{1}$
2. Account for each mass separately and their distance from the pivot

   - Distances of masses $a= \tfrac{1}{2} \ell-d$ and $b = \tfrac{1}{2} \ell + d$
   - MMOI at the pivot $I_{\rm PVT} = m a^2 + m b^2 = \tfrac{1}{2} M_{\rm sys} \left( \underbrace{ \left( \tfrac{\ell}{2} - d \right)^2 }_\text{reduced} + \underbrace{ \left( \tfrac{\ell}{2} + d \right)^2}_\text{increased} \right) \tag{2}$

Your question is how come (2) is larger than $\tfrac{1}{4} M_{\rm sys} \ell^2$, the MMOI at the center, when the fist part is decreased and the second part is increased.

Do some algebra on (2) to get $$I_{\rm PVT} = \tfrac{1}{2} M_{\rm sys} \left( \underbrace{ \tfrac{1}{4} \ell^2 - \ell d + d^2}_\text{reduced} + \underbrace{ \tfrac{1}{4} \ell^2 + \ell d + d^2}_\text{increased}   \right) = \tfrac{1}{2} M_{\rm sys} \left( \tfrac{1}{2} \ell^2 + 2 d^2 \right) $$

From this, you can see that (1) = (2) and that both calculating methods result in the same value. The trick here is that the $(\ldots  - d)^2 + (\ldots + d)^2$ terms do not completely cancel out, but produce a $\ldots + d^2$ term above which *increases* the MMOI according to the parallel axis theorem.

Comment: At first i thought that somehow that the change the moment of inertia of due to change in axis would balance out. But i think this picture is much clear.

Answer (score 1):

If you apply the same torque to two systems with different fixed axes, you will find different angular accelerations. It is harder to accelerate one, and that is reflected in the larger moment of inertia.

The math is showing you that it is easier to rotate two masses at a distance of $2$ than one mass at a distance of $4$.

Perhaps you can see it if you consider kinetic energy. $E = \tau \theta$. Apply the torque over the same angle. Both systems gain the same energy. If the mass for the second system has speed $v$, what is the speed of the two masses for the other system? What are the angular velocities? What $I$'s are needed to make $E = 1/2 I \omega^2$ come out the same for both?